# Mustache as an unknown file (IntelliJ Idea)

Tags: java, mustache

How to make the file look like an unknown file.
I have the full version of the development environment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg0F3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to "File" - > "Settings" - > "File types" and find .mustache in an unknown file type and delete it.
Don't forget to install the plugin in the IDE for mustache.